# How to match the pattern using re using the commas?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

How do I match the following pattern using re?

```
2016-02-13 02:00:00.0,3525,http://www.heatherllindsey.com/2016/02/my-husband-left-his-9-5-job-for-good-it.html,158,0,2584490
```

I used python's `split()` function to separate the attributes out but as the data is huge, the process is getting killed due to memory errors.

Comment: You should be very specific when it comes to regex. You have not supplied any attempts and we cannot be sure what you really need. *Just use `.+` to match this string* is a valid answer for such a vague question. Please clarify and add the code and regex you have written so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put the long version of string it would be better.
So how can you make it ? That is the answer:

```
import re
str = "2016-02-13 02:00:00.0,3525,http://www.heatherllindsey.com/2016/02/my-husband-left-his-9-5-job-for-good-it.html,158,0,2584490"
pattern = re.compile("(.*?),", re.DOTALL) #we use re.DOTALL to continue splitting after endlines.
result = pattern.findall(str) #we can't find the last statement (2584490) because of the pattern so we will apply second process
pattern = re.compile("(.*?)", re.DOTALL)
str2 = str[-50:-1]+str[-1] #we take last partition of string to find out last statement by using split() method

result.append(str2.split(",")[-1])
print result
```

It works...